# Fetching the value from the key in Python's dict

Tags: json, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am fetching 'value' from 'key' in JSON but I do not know why I cannot fetch the target information. Code below

```
import json 
import requests
 
#Person's ID
id=1194452

#Url
info=requests.get(f'https://api.brokercheck.finra.org/search/individual/{id}?hl=true&includePrevious=true&sort=bc_lastname_sort+asc,bc_firstname_sort+asc,bc_middlename_sort+asc,score+desc&wt=json') 

#convert to JSON
x=info.json()

 #Value
 print(x["firstName"])
```

The following is JSON of this example. (Information in the link is available to public. I, thus, do not delete the details of 1194452).

```
{'hits': {'total': 1, 'hits': [{'_type': '_doc', '_source': {'content': '{"basicInformation": {"individualId": 1194452, "firstName": "STEPHEN", "middleName": "MICHAEL", "lastName": "SCHULTZ", "otherNames": [], "bcScope": "Active", "iaScope": "NotInScope", "daysInIndustryCalculatedDate": "4/11/1984"}, "currentEmployments": [{"firmId": 5685, "firmName": "PRUCO SECURITIES, LLC.", "iaOnly": "N", "registrationBeginDate": "4/12/1984", "firmBCScope": "ACTIVE", "firmIAScope": "ACTIVE", "iaSECNumber": "52208", "iaSECNumberType": "801", "bdSECNumber": "16402", "branchOfficeLocations": [{"locatedAtFlag": "Y", "supervisedFromFlag": "N", "privateResidenceFlag": "N", "branchOfficeId": "737412", "street1": "445 Broadhollow Road", "street2": "Suite 405", "city": "Melville", "cityAlias": ["DIX HILLS", "HUNTINGTN STA", "HUNTINGTON STATION", "MELVILLE"], "state": "NY", "country": "United States", "zipCode": "11747", "latitude": "40.785118", "longitude": "-73.404965", "geoLocation": "40.785118,-73.404965", "nonRegisteredOfficeFlag": "N", "elaBeginDate": "10/15/2021"}]}], "currentIAEmployments": [], "previousEmployments": [], "previousIAEmployments": [], "disclosureFlag": "N", "iaDisclosureFlag": "N", "disclosures": [], "examsCount": {"stateExamCount": 0, "principalExamCount": 0, "productExamCount": 2}, "stateExamCategory": [], "principalExamCategory": [], "productExamCategory": [{"examCategory": "SIE", "examName": "Securities Industry Essentials Examination", "examTakenDate": "10/1/2018", "examScope": "BC"}, {"examCategory": "Series 6", "examName": "Investment Company Products/Variable Contracts Representative Examination", "examTakenDate": "4/2/1984", "examScope": "BC"}], "registrationCount": {"approvedSRORegistrationCount": 1, "approvedFinraRegistrationCount": 1, "approvedStateRegistrationCount": 1, "approvedIAStateRegistrationCount": 0}, "registeredStates": [{"state": "New York", "regScope": "BC", "status": "APPROVED", "regDate": "4/12/1984"}], "registeredSROs": [{"sro": "FINRA", "status": "APPROVED"}], "brokerDetails": {"hasBCComments": "N", "hasIAComments": "N", "legacyReportStatusDescription": "Not Requested"}}'}}]}}
```

Questions

1. Since type(x) is 'dict' in Python, why can't I fetch the value of the key?
2. What is 'hits' in JSON?  I googled 'hits' and find that it is 'Hyperlink Induced Topic Search'.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In this case, `hits` is the numbers of results of your query. It's just the keys this API is using to structure its request response.

In order to get `firstName`, you have to navigate along the nested dictionaries (accessing elements with a key) and lists (accessing elements with an index). Since you only have one hit in your case (giving a person's ID and receiving a response with total=1), you'll access the unique hit with index 0.

One thing to look out for though: the value associated with `content` is a json string. So you should read it as json.

In order to print all first names:

```py
import json

x = {'hits': {'total': 1, 'hits': [{'_type': '_doc', '_source': {'content': '{"basicInformation": {"individualId": 1194452, "firstName": "STEPHEN", "middleName": "MICHAEL", "lastName": "SCHULTZ", "otherNames": [], "bcScope": "Active", "iaScope": "NotInScope", "daysInIndustryCalculatedDate": "4/11/1984"}, "currentEmployments": [{"firmId": 5685, "firmName": "PRUCO SECURITIES, LLC.", "iaOnly": "N", "registrationBeginDate": "4/12/1984", "firmBCScope": "ACTIVE", "firmIAScope": "ACTIVE", "iaSECNumber": "52208", "iaSECNumberType": "801", "bdSECNumber": "16402", "branchOfficeLocations": [{"locatedAtFlag": "Y", "supervisedFromFlag": "N", "privateResidenceFlag": "N", "branchOfficeId": "737412", "street1": "445 Broadhollow Road", "street2": "Suite 405", "city": "Melville", "cityAlias": ["DIX HILLS", "HUNTINGTN STA", "HUNTINGTON STATION", "MELVILLE"], "state": "NY", "country": "United States", "zipCode": "11747", "latitude": "40.785118", "longitude": "-73.404965", "geoLocation": "40.785118,-73.404965", "nonRegisteredOfficeFlag": "N", "elaBeginDate": "10/15/2021"}]}], "currentIAEmployments": [], "previousEmployments": [], "previousIAEmployments": [], "disclosureFlag": "N", "iaDisclosureFlag": "N", "disclosures": [], "examsCount": {"stateExamCount": 0, "principalExamCount": 0, "productExamCount": 2}, "stateExamCategory": [], "principalExamCategory": [], "productExamCategory": [{"examCategory": "SIE", "examName": "Securities Industry Essentials Examination", "examTakenDate": "10/1/2018", "examScope": "BC"}, {"examCategory": "Series 6", "examName": "Investment Company Products/Variable Contracts Representative Examination", "examTakenDate": "4/2/1984", "examScope": "BC"}], "registrationCount": {"approvedSRORegistrationCount": 1, "approvedFinraRegistrationCount": 1, "approvedStateRegistrationCount": 1, "approvedIAStateRegistrationCount": 0}, "registeredStates": [{"state": "New York", "regScope": "BC", "status": "APPROVED", "regDate": "4/12/1984"}], "registeredSROs": [{"sro": "FINRA", "status": "APPROVED"}], "brokerDetails": {"hasBCComments": "N", "hasIAComments": "N", "legacyReportStatusDescription": "Not Requested"}}'}}]}}

for hit in x['hits']['hits']:
    person_json = json.loads(hit['_source']['content'])
    print(person_json['basicInformation']['firstName'])
```

Or get the first name of the first (and in this case only) hit:

```py
json.loads(x['hits']['hits'][0]['_source']['content'])['basicInformation']['firstName']
```

Answer (score 1):

API response as a JSON object but the required data is in `string` form of JSON object Data. So You have to call json.loads() to make into dict and `hits` means listing object of data.

**Script:**

```
import requests
import json

id = 1194452
url = f'https://api.brokercheck.finra.org/search/individual/{id}?hl=true&includePrevious=true&sort=bc_lastname_sort+asc,bc_firstname_sort+asc,bc_middlename_sort+asc,score+desc&wt=json'

response = requests.get(url)
data = response.json()

for hit in data['hits']['hits']:
    content_str = hit['_source']['content']
    content = json.loads(content_str)
    first_name = content['basicInformation']['firstName']
    print(first_name)
```

**Output:**

```
STEPHEN
```